# Telerik RadComboBox Apply SelectionBoxTemplate OnLoad?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, telerik

Basically, we have created our own custom MultiSelect-ComboBox using Telerik's RadComboBox and the SelectionBoxTemplate to make the custom text appear when multiple items are selected.

```
<ucControls:MultiSelectComboBoxBase
  ... >

<ucControls:RadComboBox
    x:Name="RadCombo"
    Text=""
    Height="22"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    DropDownClosed="RadCombo_DropDownClosed"
    IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
    CanAutocompleteSelectItems="False"
    CanKeyboardNavigationSelectItems="False"
    LostFocus="RadCombo_LostFocus">

    <ucControls:RadComboBox.SelectionBoxTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Aqua">
                <TextBlock x:Name="ComboBoxDisplay" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=RadCombo}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ucControls:RadComboBox.SelectionBoxTemplate>

    <ucControls:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox"
                          Content="{Binding ItemValue}"
                          Tag="{Binding ItemID}"
                          Height="16" Margin="2"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Visibility="{Binding IsSelectAllItem, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=NOT}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Checked="ChkBox_Checked" Unchecked="ChkBox_Unchecked"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                <HyperlinkButton
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding ItemValue}"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsSelectAllItem, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                    Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonNoBorderStyle}" Margin="3,2,0,0"
                    Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ucControls:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ucControls:RadComboBox>
```

It works great, but the only problem is that it appears that the SelectionBoxTemplate isn't actually applied when the radcombobox is loaded. It only applies when the box is clicked.
**When it loads it displays:**
[image]
**Then you click and it displays the dropdown:** [image] 

**Then you click away and it displays the correct text from the SelectionBoxTemplate:**[image]

Note I made the background color of the Textblock blue, just to show that it does not apply on the initial load.
Ideally, when it loads it should automatically apply the SelectionBoxTemplate and display the correct information rather than having the click and then click away from the multiselectcombobox.  Also, the TextBlock text is bound to the RadComboBox's text because in the code behind we set the RadComboBox's text.  There is no issue with null values or the Text not being set before because I've looked in debugging mode and all the information is there, the selection box template is just not being applied until the box receives focus.  
Is there some sort of event that has to fire off before the template is applied, or is there someway I can force the template to be applied onload?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. I've managed to solve it by setting the `SelectedIndex="0"` 
I've also read that the `SelectionBoxTemplate` only works when the RadComboBox is not editable: `IsEditable="False"`

```
<ucControls:RadComboBox
    x:Name="RadCombo"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    IsEditable="False"
    Height="22"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    DropDownClosed="RadCombo_DropDownClosed"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
    LostFocus="RadCombo_LostFocus">
...
</ucControls:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: This issue was a while ago, but I remember correctly I tried that, however that would always check the first option, and in this case it was an optional field for a search so the users wouldn't be ok always having to uncheck it.

Comment: @Max, for me this works fine. The template defined in the `SelectionBoxTemplate` is displayed which is similar as in your example (just a textblock). I however bound this to the text peroperty of the combobox. The `IsChecked` property of my items in the ItemSource are observable and handle a changed event which update the text of the combobox. For me nothing was shown without an item being selected. So Setting the SelectedIndex="0" solved that without changing any `IsChecked` properties of the ItemSource.